# Regarding usage of TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext & Task.Factory.StartNew()

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library

i am new in MS TPL. so i have seen some time people use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` when  start any task using  `Task.Factory.StartNew()` and some time `TaskScheduler` is not use when people start task.

```
var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
            });

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
            });
```

so please someone tell me what is the use of `TaskScheduler` ? when `TaskScheduler` should use along with `Task.Factory.StartNew` and when should not use `TaskScheduler`.

please explain with small sample code for better understand the usage of `TaskScheduler`.

another question how can we schedule a task like that when we create task how can i specify time or date or day when task need to start. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the given task to run on the UI thread then use the `uiScheduler` as the given `TaskScheduler`.  If you want the task to run in a thread pool thread, which is the default behavior, don't provide any `TaskScheduler`, or provide `TaskScheduler.Default`.

Comment: thank for the reply but i like to know what will be the advantage to run any task on UI thread ? can give me two sample code one for UI thread and another for thread pool using task parallel library.thanks

Comment: @Mou If you have code that needs to manipulate your user interface you run it on the UI thread, so it will actually work.  If you don't need to manipulate the UI, and want to allow the UI to manipulate itself while you do other things, you don't run it on the UI thread.  As for examples, it's literally a matter of adding the variable to the parameter list versus omitting it.  I'm entirely confident in your ability to figure out how to add or omit a parameter to a method call on your own.  If you still need examples, the MSDN docs provide them for each overload.

Comment: some where i read that uiScheduler make the process slow...is it true because i often saw people do not use uiScheduler when start any task.

Comment: just go to this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913560/want-to-use-task-parallel-library-with-progress-reporting-for-updating-database and see the answer given by @Vlad I and he did not use uiScheduler but manipulate UI from task....let me know your suggestion. thanks

Comment: @Mou Performance is irrelivant here.  If you have work that needs to be on the UI thread, it needs to be on the UI thread, and that's that.  If it shouldn't be on the UI thread then it shouldn't be on the UI thread.

Comment: @Mou Using `BeginInvoke` is the tool used in previous versions of the language to access the UI thread from another thread.  It's generally not something that you should be using in the most recent versions, barring exceptional situations.