# How to provide a feedback to UI in a async method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, task

I have been developing a windows forms project where I have a 10 tasks to do, and I would like to do this in a `async` way.
These tasks will star when the user click in a button and I call a `async` method to do this.  In my code, I already have a list of parameters for these processes.

My questions is:

> A) How transform my code to run all process in parallel? (I would like to implement async/await)
>
> B) How to provide a feedback to my UI application?

The code bellow is what I have tried:

My button to call a method to start processes

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // almost 15 process
    foreach (var process in Processes)
    {
        // call a async method to process
        ProcessObject(process);
    }
}
```

The method to simulate my process getting a parameter

```
private async void ProcessObject(ProcessViewModel process)
{
    // this is my loop scope, which I need to run in parallel
    {
       // my code is here

       // increment the progress of this process
       process.Progress++;

       // feedback to UI (accessing the UI controls)
       UpdateRow(process);
    }
}
```

I tried this, but I am not sure if it is the right way to update my UI (a grid).

```
private void UpdateRow(ProcessViewModel process)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[process.Index - 1].Cells[1].Value = process.Progress;
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: You're not awaiting `ProcessObject`. Typo or..?

Comment: No, I am just calling the ProcessObject method. I do not have a result for this method, should I change it to await?

Comment: This can also be done with TPL:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913560/want-to-use-task-parallel-library-with-progress-reporting-for-updating-database

Comment: 1) If you use async then use it all the way up the event handlers. 2) Never use `async void` except for event handlers. 3) Async without awaits is fully synchronous.

Comment: Filipe, is this Winforms or WPF?

Comment: My first sentence in the post, `I have been developing a windows forms project`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, say **no** to `async void` methods (Event handlers are exceptions) because exceptions thrown inside it will not be noticed. Instead use `async Task` and await it.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// <--Note the async modifier
{
    // almost 15 process
    foreach (var process in Processes)
    {
        // call a async method to process
        await ProcessObject(process);
    }
}

private async Task ProcessObject(ProcessViewModel process)// <--Note the return type
{
    // my code is here with some loops
    await Task.Run(()=>
    {
        //Will be run in ThreadPool thread
        //Do whatever cpu bound work here
    });

    //At this point code runs in UI thread
    process.Progress++;

    // feedback to UI
    UpdateRow(process);
}
```

However, this will start only one task at a time, once that is done it will start next. If you want to start all of them at once you can start them and use `Task.WhenAll` to await it.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// <--Note the async modifier
{
     var tasks = Processes.Select(ProcessObject).ToList();
     await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: I need to put the call of UpdateRow inside the Task.Run because I will have a loop in this process method. I tried here, but I get a error saying the my DataGridView control can be accessed by the thread because was created by another thread. I tried to pass the reference of dataGridView in my parameter but does not work, do you how can I solve this? Thank you for anwser

Comment: If you don't mind post original code. I've answered based on your code, but now you say you need to use `UpdateRow` inside `Task.Run`. That won't work. It has to be called in main thread. Also why do you need a loop there? Provide more info please.

Comment: I saw your edits, with that info I can't provide a good answer. I'll need to know which part of UI you need to update and how you're updating and so on. And also why you need to run in paralell? You're doing cup bound operation or IO bound? Need more details to answer.

Comment: Well if this is Winforms then you can call then BeginInvoke method of the dataGridView1 passing in a delegate to perform the update. dataGridView1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { //Make calls to update the UI here }));

Comment: No, don't do that. I don't recommend it. If at all you need to call `BeginInvoke` why are you using `async` method in first place? That defeats the purpose of async.

Comment: The purpose of async is to perform non blocking background operations. And when performing background operations you need to provide feedback to the UI at times. In Winforms you have to use either BeginInvoke of the control or the SynchronizationContext to achieve it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, It is a machine learning project, and the code is very long to post here. I have a loop to train some algorithms, that is the reason i increment `process.Progress++`. There is no IO bound. I just would like to know how update my UI in this async method. I have 10 processes in the `Process` list, and I have a line in the `DataGridView` with the progress of each task. I want to increment it from async method.

Comment: @dharshanajagoda Please learn about async/await. You don't need to use `SynchronizationContext` or `BeginInvoke` inside an async method. All of that is taken care by framework.

Comment: @FelipeOriani I still don't understand why do you have a async method in first place? Which operation is time consuming? We use async/await to keep UI responsive as we are performing time consuming operations(or asynchronus operations too). Which of your code takes much time to execute? If nothing like that you don't need a async method at all.

Answer (score 12):

Sriram covered how to do the async/await [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25745488/80274), however I wanted to show you another way to update the progress on the UI thread using his answer as a base.

.NET 4.5 added the [`IProgress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and the [`Progress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) class. The built in Progress class captures the synchronization context, just like async/await does, then when you go to report your progress it uses that context to make its callback (the UI thread in your case).

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var progress = new Progress<ProcessViewModel>(UpdateRow); //This makes a callback to UpdateRow when progress is reported.

     var tasks = Processes.Select(process => ProcessObject(process, progress)).ToList();
     await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async Task ProcessObject(ProcessViewModel process, IProgress<ProcessViewModel> progress)
{
    // my code is here with some loops
    await Task.Run(()=>
    {
        //Will be run in ThreadPool thread
        //Do whatever cpu bound work here


        //Still in the thread pool thread
        process.Progress++;

        // feedback to UI, calls UpdateRow on the UI thread.
        progress.Report(process); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Scott: I thought of this, but that's little useful inside async method. You could directly call `UpdateRow` inside `ProcessObject` when async method is resumed.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I agree your method is the better method (that's why your answer is the first thing I mention in my answer), but the OP seemed resistant to it, I just wanted to give other options

Comment: Ummm, +1 for your other option :)

Comment: @Scott, thank you for your anwser. I have tried here and works fine. Just to understand, now I can access the UI controls. Why the Sriram code does not can? Is recommended to add a reference to the UI controls in my argument (ProcessViewModel) and use it from the argument instead access directly from the control? Thank you.

Comment: @FelipeOriani Still you're updating the UI in main thread only. `IProgress<T>.Report` will internally pass the control to UI thread.  `UpdateRow` will be run in UI thread, that's the beauty of it. I recommend you to read [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html). If you're interested, just read all posts by stephen about TPL. He's a expert in that topic. Also note that you can't update UI from another thread. If you do so you'll get `InvalidOperationException`.