# Pass different method/function to DoWork event of Background worker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Please bear with my ignorance on this subject and on the terminology I have used. Please correct me where I am incorrect.

I have used a background Worker from the toolbox onto my form and I am passing a method to the DoWork event. What I have understood in this first attempt with background Worker is that I can use the background Worker that I've created only for 1 task. See code below:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Should call the uploadToDB1 using BackgroundWorker's DoWork event.
     backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Should call the uploadToDB2 using BackgroundWorker's DoWork event.
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void uploadToDB1()
{
    // Code for uploading to DB 1.
}        

private void uploadToDB2()
{
    // Code for uploading to DB 2.
}  

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        uploadToDB1(); // I want to change this to uploadToDB2 i.e. a variable method, How do I assign a call to this?

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = true;
    progressBar1.Maximum = maxRecords;
    lblProgress.Text = Convert.ToString(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "/" + maxRecords);
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
    lblProgress.Text = "";
}
```

I need to be able to dynamically pass a method to the DoWork event without having the need to create multiple background Workers as the actions in the rest of the events related to the background Worker remains unchanged.

Could you please advise how I should go about doing this?

Updated Code using TPL, however I am getting a cross thread error. Could you please help with a corrected code? Upload to DB 2 should happen only after upload to DB 1 is complete. So each time an upload happens the label and progress bar needs to be updated. I also need to pass different text to the label.

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(uploadToDB1);
}
private void uploadToDB1()
{
    for(i=0;i<dt.rows.count-1;i++)
    {
        // Code for inserting into DB1.

        progressbar1.maximum=dt.rows.count-1;
        progressbar1.value=i;
    }
    uploadToDB2();

}

private void uploadToDB2()
{
    for(i=0;i<dt.rows.count-1;i++)
    {
        // Code for inserting into DB2.

        progressbar1.maximum=dt.rows.count-1;
        progressbar1.value=i;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not create two background workers, one for each job?

Comment: Why not just throw the `BackgroundWorker` and use TPL?

Comment: A strategy pattern might help you too

Comment: @SriramSakthivel BackgroundWorker is for the l33t.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, Yes I did think of that but as I mentioned, the actions in the other events of the backgroundWorker are the same. I want to be able to re-use the code if possible.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, Could you give me sample code based on the above requirement? I was advised to use backgroundWorker if UI elements required to be updated.

Comment: @svb You can reuse the code just as easily with multiple background workers. After all, they're interchangeable instances. The same way, you can also quite easily decide what method to call in the background worker based on some enum field (or an argument to the background worker's `RunWorkerAsync`).

Comment: @Luan, If this is possible, can you please give me an example? I couldn't pass a method to RunWorkerAsync();

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I've updated the code using TPL, I'm using .Net 4.0, I am getting a cross thread error on the progressbar1. Could you please help me correct my mistake? I've tried my best but can't get around the concept. My understanding is that when I start a new task, the call to the respective method would run on a different thread. Am I correct?

Comment: @svb Yes, correct. It will be run in a different thread. So, you can't update the UI in that method. You're updating the progress bar in another thread, that is why you get cross thread exception. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25746088/2530848). You need to use `Progress<T>` class and call `IProgress.Report` to post the current progress which will invoke a method in the UI thread. In the linked post, `UpdateRow` is the method which will be called in UI thread. So, you won't get cross thread exception. See if that helps.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, those classes are in Net 4.5 but I am using .Net 4.0. How do I do this in 4.0?

Comment: @svb For .net 4.0 refer [this article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/06/reporting-progress-from-tasks.html). There is an example. This can be used as a general purpose solution. Use `ProgressReporter.ReportProgress` method.

Answer (score 1):

What you *can* do, and is a bit of a hack, is pass an `Action` as an argument for invocation to your `DoWorkAsync`:

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += (s, o) => 
{
    Action actualWork = (Action)o.Argument;
    actualWork();
}
```

and when you invoke `DoWorkAsync`:

```
Action action = () => DoSomething();
bw.RunWorkerAsync(action);
```

Instead, as @Sriram suggested, look into the [`Task Parallel Library`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will make you life a bit easier:

```
private async void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(UpdateFirst);
    // Update UI here.
}

private async void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(UpdateSecond);
    // Update UI again.
}
```

An extensive answer on TPL and the use of `IProgess<T>` can be found in [How to provide a feedback to UI in a async method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25745176/2530848)

Comment: There are two [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25745176/2530848) which pretty much sums up what OP wants. Use `IProgress<T>` with TPL to provide feedback to UI.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Now you tell me? :\

Comment: Would this allow me to update the label and the progress bar? If so how do I do this? The reason I ask is because, I've struggled with the progress bar matching the actual upload progress and for the first time using backgroundWorker it works like a charm.

Comment: @svb See the link provided. I've also updated my answer to include that link since it has a far more extensive answer.

Comment: @svb You're using background worker for *uploading*? That's something quite easy to handle using `await` and asynchronous I/O, no need for a separate thread.